# Save .txt file to special format

Tags: vb.net, file, export

I need to know how to be able to save a `.txt` file from my `Visual Basic 2010` program and have it saved to a special format.

I need it to save like `"monday:email@email.com" & "4/22/2013:email@email.com".`

How would I do this?

I am using Visual Basic 2010.

And there are 2 listboxes that need to be saved like that too. `"listbox1info:listbox2info"`.

I need to get my program updated `ASAP`.

How to Achive this?

My code is:

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim streamer As IO.StreamReader

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
        ListBox1.Text = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        streamer = IO.File.OpenText(ListBox1.Text)
        Dim mystring() As String = streamer.ReadToEnd.Split(vbNewLine)
        ListBox1.Items.AddRange(mystring)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
        TextBox2.Text = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button4_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
        streamer = IO.File.OpenText(TextBox2.Text)
        Dim mystring() As String = streamer.ReadToEnd.Split(vbNewLine)
        ListBox2.Items.AddRange(mystring)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Where's that monday and email@email.com from?. Depend on what you want, adjust the variable strFileName accrodingly, say it current day, current date, dynamic email address pulling from database, etc; otherwise, this will do

```
Dim strFileName As String = ""
Dim strContent As String = ""

strFileName = "monday:email@email.com" & "4/22/2013:email@email.com" & ".txt"
strContent = "whatever you want"

My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(strFileName, strContent, True)
```